# How to add an image as its own background image attribute?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

In Wordpress, I wanted to duplicate the images of the posts, so I can set one of them as background, and then blur it, creating a nice effect, without having to change all my html structure.

How can I do that, if possible, with PHP? I tried long time ago to achieve with JQuery, but at that time I didn't manage to make it:

```
$(".post-cover").each(function(){
  var img = $(this).find("img");
  $(this).css({
    "background-image": "url('"+img.prop("src")+"')",
    //Any other CSS background propriety
    //If your div don't have a fixed width and height
    width: img.width(),
    height: img.height()
  });
  img.remove();
});
```

If I used Jquery, where should I implement it?

My structure is

```
<div class="post-cover">
  <img src="#"/>
</div>
```

and the final result should be something like:

[image]

Comment: Show us your php template, if you want it

Comment: I wanted to insert in only inside the posts page. My php file of single posts is:  pastebin.com/KbiYm1ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.post-cover img').each(function() {
    $(this).before('<img src="'+ $(this).attr('src')+'" class="blur">');
  });
});
```

```css
.post-cover {
 position: relative;
}
.post-cover img {
 width: 250px;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 50px;
}

.post-cover img.blur {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
 filter: blur(25px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-cover">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch">
</div>
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to add it within the `footer.php` file on your template, presumably below the other JS scripts includes.

Comment: Is it possible to add inline, without creating a new file for this little code?

Comment: The `footer.php` file is usually present among your Wordpress template files: `wordpress-instalation-dir/wp-content/themes/footer.php`.

Comment: I could not add the jQuery code with success in my footer. Do I need to make any change before pasting? My file is here: https://pastebin.com/kbnPvaPP

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked so nice. Now I just wonder if I can place it in my single page, because I the footer is rendered in all pages anyways..

Comment: You can try to wrap this jquery script in a condition like: `<?php
if (is_singular()) { ?>your-jquery-script<?PHP } ?>`, and here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags you can find more conditions to fit your needs.

Comment: `<?php if (is_singular()) { ?>

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.post-cover img').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).before('<img src="'+ jQuery(this).attr('src')+'" class="heb-blur">');
        });
    });

<?PHP } ?>` didn't work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

For this to work you need to set the `img` source as the background of the container div and `blur` it. However, as this will blur all child elements, you will need to move the original `img` element outside of the `.post-cover` and position it absolutely so that it is still sharp. Try this:

```js
$(".post-cover").each(function() {
  var $cover = $(this);
  var $img = $cover.find("img");
  
  $cover.css({
    backgroundImage: "url('" + $img.prop("src") + "')",
    width: $img.width(),
    height: $img.height()
  });
  
  $img.insertAfter(this).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: $cover.offset().top,
    left: $cover.offset().left
  })
});
```

```css
.post-cover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(15px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-cover">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mE2HyxV.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: remember -webkit-filter: blur(10px); so that it works with the webkit browsers

Comment: I omitted it to keep the example simple, but you're right. I updated it

Comment: Should create a .js file for that function, or should I use in my functions.php or header?

Comment: you should enqueue it as a JS. file IMO.

Comment: I can't really answer that without knowing your project structure. I'd suggest putting it wherever you had the original code sample from your question. It should be in an external JS file at the very least though.

Comment: is it only running on a specific page, then you can enqueue the file on that page only.

Comment: At that time I used blogger, so It had another approach. Now that I'm new to Wordpress, I don't know where to put it. But Stender said something usefull, I'll try to implement in my loop page of single posts. How should I do it, considering it is a PHP file?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's related to the question you asked above. If you have an issue with the PHP code I'd suggest starting a new question.